# Height of div is not being overwritten by jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css, user-interface, resizable

I have 2 divs that are being resized horizontally using jquery ui resizable. The top div is being resized why using the option "alsoreverseresize" on the div underneath it. Both divs have predefined heights. Once top div is resized the bottom div takes the remaining height but is being reset to its original height in a split second.

the code i am using to recalculate the height is shownbelow:

```
        var th =  $("#defaultPolicies").height();
        var sh = $("#sidebar").height() - (54 + 100 + th);
        $("#userPolicies").css('height', sh + "px");
```

(digits 54 and 100 are static paddings) 
HTML :

```
 <section id="sidebar">
            <div class="wrapper">
                <div class="sidebarHeader">
                    <div class="wrapper">
                        <div class="search">
                            <a>
                                <div class="fieldContainer">
                                    <span class="searchLoading"><img src="images/searchingloader.gif" alt="Loading"></span>
                                    <input class="searchBox dark" type="text" name="searchHelp" id="searchHelp" value="" placeholder="Search policies...">
                                    <span data-icon="&#xe0cc;" class="searchIcon light"></span>
                                </div>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <a href="#" class="button blue" id="newPolicy">Add Policy</a>
                    </div>
                </div>



                <div class="policyContainer">
                    <div id="policyList">
                        <article id="policies">
                            <heading class="half">Default Policies <i id="arrow-default" class="icon icon-pictos-31"></i></heading>


                            <!--<a href="#" id="newPolicy">
                                <div class="addNew">
                                    <span data-icon="&#xe01c;" class="searchIcon light"></span>Add new policy
                                </div>
                            </a>-->

                            <!--<div id="line"></div>
                            <div id="divider"></div>-->
                            <div class="wrapper">

                                <ul id="defaultPolicies" class="policyList">
                                    <div class="subLabel">On | Off</div>
                                    <div class="line"></div>
                                    <script id="sidebar_default_policies" type="text/x-handlebars-template">

                                        {{#each defaults}}

                                        <li class="{{#if unsortable}}unsortable{{/if}}" data-role="{{role}}">
                                          <div class="switch {{#if enabled}}on{{/if}}"></div>
                                          <div class="policyBox {{#if enabled}}on{{/if}}" data-link="{{id}}">

                                            <div class="policyName {{#if unsortable}}margin{{/if}}"> <span class="icon" data-icon="{{#if unsortable}}&#xe05a;{{/if}}"></span> 
                                                <div class="name">{{name}}</div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="orderNum"></div>
                                          </div>
                                        </li>

                                        {{/each}}
                                    </script>

                                </ul>

                            </div>
                        </article>


                        <article id="customPolicies">
                            <heading class="half">Custom Policies <i id="arrow-user" class="icon icon-pictos-31"></i></heading>

                            <div class="wrapper">

                               <ul id="userPolicies" class="policyList">
                                    <div class="line"></div>
                                    <script id="sidebar_user_policies" type="text/x-handlebars-template">

                                        {{#each policies}}

                                        <li class="{{#if unsortable}}unsortable{{/if}}" data-role="{{role}}">
                                          <div class="switch {{#if enabled}}on{{/if}}"></div>
                                          <div class="policyBox {{#if enabled}}on{{/if}}" data-link="{{id}}" data-isdefault="{{#if isDefault}}true{{/if}}">

                                            <div class="policyName {{#if unsortable}}margin{{/if}}"> <span class="icon" data-icon="{{#if unsortable}}&#xe05a;{{/if}}"></span> 
                                                <div class="name">{{name}}</div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="orderNum"></div>
                                          </div>
                                        </li>

                                        {{/each}}
                                    </script>   

                                </ul>

                            </div>
                        </article>
                    <div>
                </div>
            </div> <!-- end of wrapper -->

            <div id="editSidebar">

                <div class="wrapper">

                    <div class="sidebarHeader">
                        <div id="title">
                            <span class="icon" data-icon="&#xe05e;"></span>
                            <p>Drag elements to create policy<p>
                        </div>
                        <!--<ul>
                            <li>
                                <button data-link="section1" class="on">
                                    <span class="icon" data-icon="&#xe187;"></span>
                                </button>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <button data-link="section2">
                                    <span class="icon" data-awesome="&#xe109;"></span>
                                </button>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <button data-link="section3">
                                    <span class="icon" data-icon="&#xe20c;"></span>
                                </button>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <button data-link="section4">
                                    <span class="icon" data-icon="&#xe032;"></span>
                                </button>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <button data-link="section5">
                                    <span class="icon more" data-awesome="6"></span>
                                </button>
                            </li>
                        </ul>-->
                    </div>

                    <div class="policyContainer">

                        <!-- ############ Applies To ############ -->
                       <!-- <article id="section1">
                            <heading>Applies To</heading>

                            <div class="wrapper">
                                <ul class="policyList">
                                    <li>
                                        <div class="policyBox" data-role="usergroup">
                                            <div class="policyContent">
                                                <span class="icon" data-icon="&#xe187;"></span>
                                                <p>Everyone</p>
                                            </div>
                                        </div> 
                                    </li>

                                    <li>
                                        <div class="policyBox" data-role="usergroup">
                                            <div class="policyContent">
                                                <span class="icon" data-icon="&#xe187;"></span>
                                                <p>Users, Groups, IPs</p>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </article>-->

                        <!-- ############ Filters ############ -->
                        <article id="section2">
                            <heading>Apply policy to:</heading>

                            <div class="wrapper">
                                <ul class="policyList">
                                    <!--<li id="userFilter" class="hide">
                                        <div class="policyBox" data-role="usergroup">
                                            <div class="policyContent">
                                                <span class="icon" data-icon="&#xe187;"></span>
                                                <p>Users + Groups</p>
                                                <a href="#" class="addIcon"></a>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </li>-->

                                    <li>
                                        <div class="policyEl" data-role="websites">
                                            <div class="policyContent">
                                                <span class="icon" data-icon="&#xe00d;"></span>
                                                <p>Websites</p>
                                                <a href="#" class="addIcon"></a>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </li>

                                    <li>
                                        <div class="policyEl" data-role="applications">
                                            <div class="policyContent">
                                                <span class="icon custom applications"></span>
                                                <p>Applications</p>
                                                <a href="#" class="addIcon"></a>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </li>

                                    <li>
                                        <div class="policyEl" data-role="filetypes">
                                            <div class="policyContent">
                                                <span class="icon custom fileTypes"></span>
                                                <p>File Types</p>
                                                <a href="#" class="addIcon"></a>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </li>

                                    <li>
                                        <div class="policyEl" data-role="exceptions">
                                            <div class="policyContent">
                                                <span class="icon custom exceptions"></span>
                                                <p>Exceptions</p>
                                                <a href="#" class="addIcon"></a>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </li>

                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </article>


                        <!-- ############ Threshold ############ -->
                        <article id="section3">
                            <heading>Set limit by:</heading>

                            <div class="wrapper">
                                <ul class="policyList">
                                    <li>
                                        <div class="policyEl" data-role="bandwidth">
                                            <div class="policyContent">
                                                <span class="icon" data-icon="&#xe022;"></span>
                                                <p>Bandwidth Limit</p>
                                                <a href="#" class="addIcon"></a>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </li>

                                    <li>
                                        <div class="policyEl" data-role="time">
                                            <div class="policyContent">
                                                <span class="icon" data-icon="&#xe14f;"></span>
                                                <p>Time Limit</p>
                                                <a href="#" class="addIcon"></a>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </li>

                                    <li>
                                        <div class="policyEl" data-role="hits">
                                            <div class="policyContent">
                                                <span class="icon" data-icon="&#xe16f;"></span>
                                                <p>Hits Limit</p>
                                                <a href="#" class="addIcon"></a>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </li>

                                    <!--
                                    <li>
                                        <div class="policyEl" data-role="streaming">
                                            <div class="policyContent">
                                                <span class="icon" data-icon="&#xe20c;"></span>
                                                <p>Streaming</p>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </li>
                                    -->
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </article>


                        <!-- ############ Notify ############ -->
                        <article id="section4">
                            <heading>Notify:</heading>

                            <div class="wrapper">
                                <ul class="policyList">
                                    <li>
                                        <div class="policyEl" data-role="breacher">
                                            <div class="policyContent">
                                                <span class="icon" data-icon="&#xe032;"></span>
                                                <p>Breacher</p>
                                                <a href="#" class="addIcon"></a>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </li>

                                    <li>
                                        <div class="policyEl" data-role="administrator">
                                            <div class="policyContent">
                                                <span class="icon" data-icon="&#xe032;"></span>
                                                <p>Adminstrator</p>
                                                <a href="#" class="addIcon"></a>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </article>

                       <!-- ############ Schedule ############ -->
                        <article id="section5">
                            <heading>Other:</heading>

                            <div class="wrapper">
                                <ul class="policyList">
                                    <!--<li>
                                        <div class="policyEl" data-role="scheduler">
                                            <div class="policyContent">
                                                <span class="icon" data-icon="&#xe0a1;"></span>
                                                <p>Schedule</p>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </li>-->

                                    <li>
                                        <div class="policyEl" data-role="expiry">
                                            <div class="policyContent">
                                                <span class="icon" data-icon="&#xe1fc;"></span>
                                                <p>Policy Expiry</p>
                                                <a href="#" class="addIcon"></a>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </li>

                                    <li>
                                        <div class="policyEl" data-role="logging">
                                            <div class="policyContent">
                                                <span class="icon" data-icon="&#xe23f;"></span>
                                                <p>Logging</p>
                                                <a href="#" class="addIcon"></a>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </article>

                    </div>
                </div> <!-- end of wrapper -->
            </div>
        </section> <!-- end of sidebar -->
```

anyone know why the height isnt being overwritten?
Thanks

Comment: Very had to understand without some html code too please

Comment: i have included my html. i am trying to resize divs #defaultPolicies and #userPolicies - @HelloUniverse

Answer (score 1):

Try using the height attribute,

```
$('#userPolicies').height(sh);
```

Comment: i tried but the same thing happens - height is applied but reset to the original in a split second @Cristi Marian

Comment: In this case you have to see what's causing the reset. Check your DOM for inline styles (if there are any, it's a JS issue, somewhere in your code resets the height of the element). If there are no inline styles it could be a CSS rule makred with "!important", but i doubt it, usually the css loads before all js.

Comment: @user22 , you can try to make a fiddle for us, in order to see exactly what is happening, but i bet in the fiddle, your code will work

Comment: i made sure to not use any important rules. the below is the only css the element has: 
#userPolicies{
 height: calc(100% - 355px);
 overflow-y:scroll !important;
}

Comment: remove the calc(100% - 355px);  if you're already using jquery to calculate the height of the element, why do you need to have the same thing in both  jquery and css ?

Comment: its cause i tried both a predefined height as well as using calc and neither attempts worked

Comment: ok, in this case please make a jsfiddle and we'll see how we can solve this

Comment: try to reproduce just this issue, don't insert unnecessary code